# Excel Search Bar

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to build a database in an excel file.
I would like to make a search bar where users can type and search for the data in the whole excel file that interests them.

I am stuck, i've tried macros but i cant get it to work.

Any suggestions? or help?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Excel already has a search tool. Ctrl-F. If you want to roll your own, please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: Please expand on your question; it is not clear where you are "stuck".  If you are stuck at getting the function to search the entire work book, then I concur with @teylyn about using the existing search facility.  If it is that you can't get your "search bar" to display, you need to provide more information; i.e., code.

Comment: May be you are looking for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNpFB8M1-dI)

Comment: "I'm trying to build a database in an excel file" Are you sure that is really a good idea? Have you considered using a *database* to build a database? Often things work better if you use them for what they were intended. There are good reasons why databases usually aren't built in Excel.

Comment: Thanks to all the responses.